# How to disable editing of JavaFX HTMLEditor?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to disable editing in an HTMLEditor in JavaFX. According to the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html):

> Note that if the contentEditable property on the  tag of the
> provided HTML is not set to true, the HTMLEditor will become
> read-only.
> You can ensure that the text remains editable by ensuring the body appears as such:
>
> `<body contentEditable="true">`

However this doesn't work for me. If I use the following component, the HTML Editor is editable contrary to the documentation. Even if I specifically add `contentEditable="false"` to the body tag, it is still editable. How can I really disable editing?

**Example Component**

```
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;

public class HighlightedTextArea extends HTMLEditor
{
    public HighlightedTextArea()
    {
        setHtmlText("<html><body contentEditable=\"false\">Hello World</body></html>");
    }
}
```

I am using JavaFX 12.0.1 using Maven from org.openjfx with Java OpenJDK 12.0.1.u12-1.

Comment: I am not sure if it's case-sensitive. Try: `contenteditable='false'` It works in 11.0.2. I would guess that they didn't make any changes when moving to 12.0.1. I could be wrong.

Comment: you can `setDisable(true)` …

Comment: @trilogy: That works, thanks! I expected that to disable the whole component, not just editing.

Comment: @Sedrick: This doesn't work for me. It is in also camel case in the documentation.

Comment: … I think it does disable the whole component... how did you get it to disable editing only?

Comment: @trilogy: I just used your statement `setDisable(true)`. I think that "disabled" in this case is working as intended meaning "still shown but not editable".

Comment: Note that [`disable`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty) is a property of `Node`. Setting it to `true` will disable the entire `HTMLEditor`, which has the effect of making it non-editable; however, _everything_ about will be disabled (e.g. you can't interact with the toolbars). Disabled nodes also typically have their opacity set to `< 1` by `modena.css`. The point being that the `disable` property has different semantics than, for instance, the `editable` property of `TextInputControl`.

Comment: @Slaw: You are right, I cannot use the scroll bar anymore when using the disable property.